# Any way to speed this up?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
for x in range(1, num_sims + 1):
  output_lines[x]=output_lines.QB.map(NFL_sim.set_index('Player')[x].to_dict())
```

I'm wondering if this is the most efficient way to write this expression. This is a for loop in a bigger for loop, where all other parts of my for loop take a combined 0.1 seconds, but this one section takes 5 seconds.

Comment: almost surely, but its impossible to know what you're trying to do without example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `iloc`:

```
payouts.iloc[:, 1: 100] = payouts.iloc[:, 1: 100] / payouts.Lineup.map(output_lines_with_mine.set_index('Lineup')['Dupes'].to_dict())
```

Comment: Instead of the for loop your suggesting?

Comment: @ScottWoodhall Yes, this would run much faster :D

Comment: the ['Dupes'] portion of the code from above is integral, can you add that to your code line please.

Comment: "TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on Index with these indexers [1001] of type int" unfortunately it did not. Does this mean it can't slice because the index 'Lineup' is an integer as opposed to a string?

Comment: @ScottWoodhall What does `print(type(payouts))` output?

Comment: It's a <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: @ScottWoodhall Edited my answer should work now.

Comment: I changed a different portion of the code, is there a way to speed this up as well?